# Call the more general method from a specific one

Tags: julia

I am trying to call a general method from a specific one, but cannot figure out how.

```
function fn(x)
  # generic
  ...
end

function fn(x :: String)
  # I want to call the generic version here
  val = fn(x)
  # do something with val and then return it
  ...
end
```

Is this possible?

A workaround is using a helper function that can be called from both generic and specific methods. e.g.

```
function helper(x)
  # main work is here
  ...
end

function fn(x)
  # generic
  helper(x)
end

function fn(x :: String)
  val = helper(x)
  # now use the val to do something
  ...
end
```

Without using such helpers, is there a way to control the dispatch to select a particular method to use? Is there something like `:before` and `:after` keywords and `call-next-method` from lisp CLOS in Julia?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the `invoke` function:

```
julia> function fn(x)
         @info "generic $x"
       end
fn (generic function with 1 method)

julia> function fn(x :: String)
         @info "before"
         invoke(fn, Tuple{Any}, x)
         @info "after"
       end
fn (generic function with 2 methods)

julia> fn(10)
[ Info: generic 10

julia> fn("10")
[ Info: before
[ Info: generic 10
[ Info: after
```

(just to be clear - the printing of `"before"` and `"after"` is only to highlight what gets executed in what sequence - the only thing that is related to method dispatch here is the `invoke` function)

Comment: Note that while you can do this, the `helper` method is probably a much better solution.

Comment: yes, and this pattern is used very commonly in Julia.

Comment: Most often you would use `invoke` if you need to call a specific method in a module you do not own.